# Is person accounts available in Service Cloud?

Tags: servicecloud, person-accounts

for a project, I need to enable person accounts feature in Service Cloud but I can't find any response in the Salesforce documentation.

Do you have a link that says if it is possible or not?

Comment: I do not know any issue to use Person Account. Would you like to open a Case for example? What feature are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to use PersonAccounts in Service Cloud. The documentation states that the Service Cloud Cases are compatible with PersonAccounts:

> On cases, person accounts can be entered in the Account Name field, the Contact Name field, or both.
> (Source: [Considerations for Using Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_behavior.htm&type=5))

Steps should be the same as in the Sales Cloud documentation:

> 1. Make sure you meet the following prerequisites.
>
>    - The account object has at least one record type.
>    - User profiles that have read permission on accounts have read permission on contacts.
>    - The organization-wide default sharing is set so that either Contact is Controlled by Parent or both Account and Contact are Private.
> 2. From Setup, enter Account Settings in the Quick Find box, and then select Allow Customer Support to enable Person Accounts. We’ll verify your org meets the prerequisites, then send you an email with additional information. If you don’t see a message verifying you meet the prerequisites, go back to step 1.
> 3. Contact Salesforce Customer Support by logging a case to enable Person Accounts. Refer to the email we sent about what to include in the case.
> 4. After Person Accounts is enabled, a person account record type is created. You can create additional record types for person account if needed.
> 5. Assign the person account record type to user profiles.
>    (Source: [Enable Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=account_person_enable.htm&type=5))

**Note:** Salesforce Support will ask you if you are sure about activating PersonAccounts as this cannot be undone once provisioned.